# Could not resolve module when starting an OSGi bundle

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

I have developed a OSGi bundle with NetBeans, in the karaf deploy. It is in status installed, I execute the start bundle command, it sends me an error :

```
karaf@trun()> start 288
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Error starting bundle 288: Could not resolve module: com.mycompany.mavenproject1 [288]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: de.odysseus.staxon.json
```

Does anyone have a solution for this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dependency for the package de.odysseus.staxon.json in your pom.xml